# Stains on an oiled wood floor

Tags: wood, floor, stain-removal

I'm my kitchen I have a floor made of oil treated wood. I do not know the type of wood as it's not clear from the manufacturers info that I have. I also did not buy or install it myself as this is a rented apartment.

There is a spot in front of the dishwasher with stains that I cannot remove with the regular wood floor cleaner nor with dish washing soap. I have not dared to use anything stronger on it yet! I do not know what caused the stains, but my guess is, that it's drippings from the dirty dishes or even water from the dishwasher that has dropped out when the for was accidentally opened during operation.

[image: stain 1]
[image: stain 2]

My question is, how to remove these stains or at least make them less visible?

Comment: I'd try hitting it with a weak bleach solution.  If that has no effect, I'd step up to a strong bleach solution.

Comment: Are the stains new since you moved in or where they there before you? Have you asked the landlord about what type of flooring you've got? She'd probably be happy to share the info, knowing you're trying to clean up after yourself. Using the wrong thing could make matters _much_ worse and cost you much more than your damage deposit, while asking about the flooring and admitting to making the stain might earn you some goodwill credits for trying to clean up after yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Oxalic Acid is the traditional method to "bleach" stains in wood floors (or just bleach wood, period.) In this case using a small paintbrush to apply it just to the stain (and perhaps starting with "only the worst of the stain, since if you lighten it then you might get a more even result with a second application to the less stained part around it.)

You'll want to avoid overdoing it and creating a noticeably lighter spot.